# Raspberry Pi 4 8gig Ubuntu server 20.10 wifi power management and interface down

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

I am trying to get my Pi 4 setup with Ubuntu 20.10 server using WIFI. I have setup the WIFI correctly at the time of creating the image. I know this because I have a RBI 3B+ that I have done the same exact thing with and it works perfectly. Both Pis are booting via USB SSD.

The first issue I am having is that power management is always enabled on wlan0. I can disable it manually by running "sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off". If there is any way to permanently turn off the power_save on wlan0, I have not found one.

The second issue I have is, once power_save is set to off, I cannot get the wlan0 interface to come up. I have tried "sudo ip link set wlan0 up" but that does not appear to do anything as when I check the status of wlan0 it state is still DOWN.

I know it is not a hardware failure because I can stick a SD card with Raspberry Pi OS in and connect via WIFI.

This is the 50-cloud.init.yaml file that I am using:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: yes
            match:
                driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
            optional: true
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    wifis:
      wlan0:
        access-points:
          {SSID}:
            password: {pw}
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
```

When is apply the netplan using the -debug flag I only get a warning with the status of power_save on wlan01 regardless if it on or off.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps you ask at the wrong place. This is not a raspi question, it's rather a ubuntu one, I think ;-). https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on Even if the link doesn't answer your question. IMHO there you'll get better answers. Look at the last answer, it's the newest. I have no ubuntu server running, so I can not say if anyting of that is applicable for 20.10.

Comment: Nothing on that page helps me. This is a Pi issue for sure. In my question I noted that I have no issues with the same configuration on my RPi 3B+. Both Pis are running Ubuntu 20.10 and the config is identical. There is deftly something up with the power management on the RP 4. I can bring wlan0 out of power management but will never stay off not matter what I have tired.

Comment: I did not try to convince you that it is a Ubuntu question. I just gave you a tipp. I think it would be better to ask on SO ubuntu. It seems to be a configuration issue. Many people here (including me)  have good knowledge about Raspian, but not so much with Ubuntu. I also mentioned that the linked page hardly could help you, but that's the place where you should ask.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what tools you have in Ubuntu, you can try the following

For NetworkManager, edit `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

For TLP, edit `/etc/default/tlp`

```
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=off
```

Regarding your second issue, you should check the kernel log after trying to bring the interface up. Chances are, there are error messages in it explaining what's wrong. Loading `brcmfmac` with `debug` parameter set to 2 or 3 could get you more messages:

```
modprobe brcmfmac debug=3
```